# \lstlistoflistings does not add spaces by chapter

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, listings

I'm quite new in LaTeX and ended up with this problem: I'm using list of tables and list of lstlistings (`\listoftables`, `\lstlistoflistings`), both numbered by chapter. List of tables does add spaces before new chapters, list of lstlistings does not (see images below). How I can unify this behavior? I would prefer to create spaces also in list of lstlistings, but removing it from list of tables is still more suitable than the current situation. Thanks for advices.

//edit: added minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
\begin{table}
\caption{Foo table}
\end{table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo script]
...
\end{lstlisting}

\chapter{bar}

\begin{table}
\caption{Bar table}
\end{table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Bar script]
...
\end{lstlisting}

\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) According to your images, the question is rather about [tag:spacing], not [tag:indentation].

Comment: Also, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (e.g.,shows what document class you use).

Comment: It depends on which document class you are using. At least the `memoir` class has a special macro that added this extra space to the list of figures and list of tables, that macro could then be redefined to includ additions to list of listings as well.

Comment: thanks, example added. I don't use memoir and don't know even what it is. Would it help me somehow?

Comment: Please try `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}\usepackage{scrhack}` as document class

Comment: Marco Daniel: thanks very much, that helped. Feel free to post it as an answer, I'll mark it correct to give you rep.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I suggest you add an answer to the "original" question instead.